# Is my code doing camera calibration correctly?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I've have read every single Camera Calibration and 3D reconstruction and I can not find anyone with code more than the documentation. So, with that being said, I have my Camera Calibration code in which I take multiple pictures on the spot that are saved for Camera Calibration. I am sure that everything works except for the actual Camera Calibration. Whenever I undistort using Cv2.undistort, I never get a good image and instead get a chunk that isn't even part of the checkerboard. Am I doing something incorrectly?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0
imgNames = []
size = (7,5)
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    gray =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("test", gray)
    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        img_name = "{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame) 
        imgtemp = cv2.imread(img_name)
        graytemp = cv2.cvtColor(imgtemp,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(graytemp, size,None)
        print (ret)
        if ret == True:
            print ("good!")
            imgNames.append(img_name)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            img_counter += 1
        else:
            print ("again")

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 
0.001)
objp = np.zeros((7*5,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:size[0],0:size[1]].T.reshape(-1,2) #multiply by 
length
objpoints = [] 
imgpoints = [] 

for fname in imgNames:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray,size,None)

    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11), 
(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
    ret,mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, 
imgpoints,gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    h,  w = img.shape[:2]
    newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1, 
(w,h))
    # undistort
    dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

    # crop the image
    x,y,w,h = roi
    dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('calibresult.png',dst)
    #Save parameters into numpy file
    np.save("ret", ret)
    np.save("mtx", mtx)
    np.save("dist", dist)
    np.save("rvecs", rvecs)
    np.save("tvecs", tvecs)
```

What is supposed to happen is that I get an undistorted image and the matrix is saved. However, the image is random and I don't understand what is going wrong. I've looked at everything that pops up under Camera Calibration on Google and all Stack overflow questions. 
I'm using https://medium.com/@omar.ps16/stereo-3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-using-an-iphone-camera-part-ii-77754b58bfe0 and https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

Thanks ahead of time!
Also sorry for posting so many questions. I just can't find answers anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)` after you have appended `objpoints` and `imgpoints` from all the images you have. It should not be in the for loop.

In addition, make sure you have enough images for getting a good calibration result.